# CMake built Qt5 QMediaPlayer program fails only when installed

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5

I have a simple Qt 5.4 application that uses QMediaPlayer.  I build it using CMake.  The executable created from running "make" works correctly and plays the song.  The executable created and installed from running "make install" gives the following error on Ubuntu 14.04

defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"

My code:

```
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QMediaPlayer myAudio;
  myAudio.setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/absolute/path/song.mp3"));
  myAudio.setVolume(50);
  myAudio.play();
  return app.exec();
}
```

My CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
project(QtTestingExe)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Multimedia REQUIRED)
add_executable(QtTesting QtTesting.cpp)
target_link_libraries(QtTesting Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Multimedia)
install(TARGETS QtTesting DESTINATION bin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably related to the CMake RPATH handling. Quoting from [Cmake docs](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling):

"CMake will link the executables and shared libraries with full RPATH to all used libraries in the build tree. When installing, it will clear the RPATH of these targets so they are installed with an empty RPATH"

This may explain the behavior you're observing.

If this is indeed the case, adding the QT path to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable will probably be enough.

Alternatively the CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH could be set to the correct path inside the CMakeLists.txt.

There are more options to play with RPATH settings in CMakeLists.txt - see the documentation link above.

Comment: This was exactly right.  I had Qt installed in a non-standard location.